# Why does my ASP.NET program look and function properly in Debug mode, but does not once published to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-6

Using a combination of Javascript and PartialViews, I have a list of items (favorites list) that I can add to or remove from with button clicks.

When a user clicks the "Add to Favorites" button, the selected item is added to a model (List) in the Controller and passed to the PartialView that is then displayed on the page on the page with the newly added favorite. Likewise, each favorite has a delete button next to it, that when clicked, removes that particular item from the favorites list, and refreshes the PartialView to reflect the changes on the screen.

This all works well. When I deploy the site to the IIS server, items are added and removed from the list (and thus the database) correctly, but the PartialView that displays this to the user does not. A manual refresh of the page reflects these changes.

With all of the above being said, having to manually refresh the entire page really isn't acceptable.

What causes this type of issue? I'm not sure if it is related, but Visual elements change as well. For example, my Bootstrap icon disappears in the published version of the website, but works just fine while debugging.

I have ran the site in both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

[Debug Version of Favorites Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRGUs.png)

[Published Version of Favorites Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRBZ.png)

The reason that I am not pasting any code is to keep things as simple as possible, as it may just be a settings issue. If code is required, please let me know, and I will try my best to create a sample code that does the same thing.

Thanks ahead of time.

**Update:**

I was able to solve the issue of the list updating by wrapping my PartialView in an Ajax.BeginForm:

```
 <div id="myFavorites"  class="Favorites">
                            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Favorites", "Reports", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "myFavorites" }))
                            {
                                { Html.RenderAction("Favorites", "Reports");}
                            }                               
                        </div>
```

I then called the section to reload when my add or remove buttons are clicked.

```
$('#FavoritesCell').click(function () {
            $('#myFavorites').load('@Url.Action("Favorites", "Reports")')
        });
```

The issue of the glyphs and visual elements remain however.

Comment: I'm still new to this, please let me know why a downvote would be given.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my updated question, I resolved the list updating by wrapping my form in an ajax call.

The Bootstrap issue was resolved by going to **Turn Windows features on or off** and checking the following.

1. Internet Information Services
2. World Wide Web Services
3. Common HTTP Features
4. Static Content